# HTML, php function within variables are not showing up correctly

Tags: php, html, css

In php, I have the $form variable that contains the EchoTest() function between some texts. The texts before and after EchoTest() function has CSS tags. But on the website, function EchoTest() shows up before the entire variable $form (not where the function was placed) and without any style.

**In PHP:**

```
function EchoTest(){
echo 'EchoTest 1 with single quote <br>';
echo "EchoTest 2 with double quote <br>";
}


$form ='<h3>Note: Fill in the required filed.</h3>
<span style="color:red">'.EchoTest().'</span>
<h3>Fields with * are required.</h3>'
```

**HTML (Firefox - View Page Source)**

```
EchoTest 1 with single quote
EchoTest 2 with double quote
<h3>Note: Fill in the required filed.</h3>

<h3>Fields with * are required.</h3>
<span style="color:red"></span>
```

As far as I understand, EchoTest() function should be displayed with in body and not above.

I tried removing the span, h tags, no tags. It simply enough it should work. Not sure what am I missing.

Comment: You `echo $form;` at the end ?

Comment: The code you've shared can't produce the given output. Also, running `echo`  in a function **immediately** displays the given string. Also, this question looks completely unrelated to HTML or CSS to me, isn't it?

Comment: To Dipankar this looked related to HTML because the function is outputting markup and to CSS because the styling didn't apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `echo` in the function, as it outputs the strings directly.
Use `return` instead:

```php
function EchoTest(){
  return 'EchoTest 1 with single quote <br>' .
         "EchoTest 2 with double quote <br>";
}


$form ='<h3>Note: Fill in the required filed.</h3>
<span style="color:red">'.EchoTest().'</span>
<h3>Fields with * are required.</h3>'
```

This way the return value of `EchoTest()` is put together with the other HTML markup.

Of course the name "EchoTest" is then misleading - you were just experimenting with echo. So in general, write functions that return their markup.

Comment: Thank you Peter for your answer and comment above, and you are right.